# Bundling a directory in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bundle

For a project, I need to launch a Unity Project from a C# Script, which is pretty easy.
The hard part is that I can't seem to include the Unity build in such a way that it is included in the final .exe.

My final goal is to have only one .exe (the one that i'm coding right now) and to be able to hide the unity build from people.

Is there any way to bundle the Unity project with my code or really any other way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

You could always put the Unity project in a subdirectory, or have an installer that puts it somewhere else. There is no way to "bundle" it within a single file, as Unity will require the same project structure as built to run.

Comment: in that case is there a way to really hide the Unity project? And I don't mean putting it in a directory somewhere else, I mean not visible by a lambda user

Comment: The folder will need to be somewhere, but you could always mark it as hidden, or only extract it when the user launches the program and delete it afterwards. May I ask why you are trying to hide it? There might be other solutions depending on your goal.

Comment: My assignment is to create a protection at launch for a unity project that will delete everything when launched on the wrong computer.
I've already figured and coded everything else, just missing the part that doesn't allow people to launch the Unity Project if it wasn't launched by my code

Comment: Is this a hypothetical assignment / assignment for Uni OR a real world use case for a game you want to release? If it is for the second then that would be the most infuriating protection mechanism and there are many better ways to solve this. If it is for the first, I would just have the entire unity directory compressed with a password or encrypted, and have a launcher app that if run on the correct computer would decompress / unencrypt to a temp location and launch the exe. And when it exits remove that temp directory.